# Get dash video properties with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Hope it`s all good!

I have a video tag with a dash video source (.mp4, .mpd). How could I get the current time and duration in order to alter the time when this video will start to loop?

I tried the code below, but I get *undefined* in the console for video duration and currentTime.

```
                 video.on('timeupdate', function(){
                    console.log(video.duration);
                    console.log(video.currentTime);

                    if(video.currentTime < video.duration - 10){
                        // Reset the video to 0
                        video.currentTime = 0;
                        // And play again
                        video.play();
                    }
                  });
```

Does anyone know how to target/get those properties with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

just check 'console.log(video)' and see if you even get the obj of video and if so, what properties are available.

---

Srry I still can't just comment, my reputation didnt reach 50... XD